# How does compose function work with multiple parameters?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, composition, currying, partial-application

Here's a 'compose' function which I need to improve:

```
const compose = (fns) => (...args) => fns.reduceRight((args, fn) => [fn(...args)], args)[0];
```

Here's a practical implementation of one:

```js
const compose = (fns) => (...args) => fns.reduceRight((args, fn) => [fn(...args)], args)[0];

const fn = compose([
  (x) => x - 8,
  (x) => x ** 2,
  (x, y) => (y > 0 ? x + 3 : x - 3),
]);

console.log(fn("3", 1)); // 1081
console.log(fn("3", -1)); // -8
```

And here's an improvement my mentor came to.

```
const compose = (fns) => (arg, ...restArgs) => fns.reduceRight((acc, func) => func(acc, ...restArgs), arg);
```

If we pass arguments list like that func(x, [y]) with first iteration, I still don't understand how do we make function work with unpacked array of [y]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Let's analyse what the improved `compose` does

```js
compose = (fns) =>
          (arg, ...restArgs) =>
          fns.reduceRight((acc, func) => func(acc, ...restArgs), arg);
```

When you feed `compose` with a number of functions, you get back... a function. In your case you give it a name, `fn`.

What does this `fn` function look like? By simple substitution you can think of it as this:

```js
(arg, ...restArgs) => fns.reduceRight((acc, func) => func(acc, ...restArgs), arg);
```

where `fns === [(x) => x - 8, (x) => x ** 2, (x, y) => (y > 0 ? x + 3 : x - 3)]`.

So you can feed this function `fn` with some arguments, that will be "pattern-matched" against `(arg, ...restArgs)`; in your example, when you call `fn("3", 1)`, `arg` is `"3"` and `restArgs` is `[1]` (so `...restArgs` expands to just `1` after the comma, so you see that `fn("3", 1)` reduces to

```js
fns.reduceRight((acc, func) => func(acc, 1), "3");
```

From this you see that

1. the rightmost function, `(x, y) => (y > 0 ? x + 3 : x - 3)` is called with the two arguments `"3"` (the initial value of `acc`) and `1`,
2. the result will be passed as the first argument to the middle function with the following call to `func`,
3. and so on,

but the point is that the second argument to `func`, namely `1`, is only used by the rightmost function, whereas it is passed to **but ignored** by the other two functions!

### Conclusion

Function composition is a thing between unary functions.¹ Using it with functions with higher-than-1 arity leads to confusion.²

For instance consider these two functions

```js
square = (x) => x**2;   // unary
plus = (x,y) => x + y;  // binary
```

can you compose them? Well, you can compose them into a function like this

```js
sum_and_square = (x,y) => square(plus(x,y));
```

the `compose` function that you've got at the bottom of your question would go well:

```js
sum_and_square = compose([square, plus]);
```

But what if your two functions were these?

```js
apply_twice = (f) => ((x) => f(f(x))); // still unary, technically
plus = (x,y) => x + y;                 // still binary
```

Your `compose` would not work.

Even though, if the function `plus` was curried, e.g. if it was defined as

```js
plus = (x) => (y) => x + y
```

then one could think of composing them in a function that acts like this:

```js
f = (x,y) => apply_twice(plus(x))(y)
```

which would predictably produce `f(3,4) === 10`.

You can get it as `f = compose([apply_twice, plus])`.

### A cosmetic improvement

Additionally, I would suggest a "cosmetic" change: make `compose` accept `...fns` instead of `fns`,

```js
compose = (...fns)/* I've only added the three dots on this line */ =>
          (arg, ...restArgs) =>
          fns.reduceRight((acc, func) => func(acc, ...restArgs), arg);
```

and you'll be able to call it without groupint the functions to be composed in an array, e.g. you'd write `compose(apply_twice, plus)` instead of <s>`compose([apply_twice, plus])`</s>.

### Btw, there's [`lodash`](https://lodash.com/)

There's two functions in that library that can handle function composition:

- [`_.flow`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#flow)
- [`_.flowRight`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#flowRight), which is aliased to `_.compose` in [`lodash/fp`](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/wiki/FP-Guide)

---

(¹) This is Haskell's choice ([`.`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:.) is the composition operator in Haskell). If you apply `f . g . h` to more than one argument, the first argument will be passed thought the whole pipeline; that intermediate result will be applied to the second argument; that further intermediate result will be applied to the third argument, and so on. In other words, if you had `haskellCompose` in JavaScript, and if `f` was binary and `g` and `h` unary, `haskellCompose(f, g, h)(x, y)` would be equal to `f(g(h(x)), y)`.

(²) Clojure's [`comp`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/comp) instead takes another choice. It saturates the rightmost function and then passes the result over to the others. So if you had `clojureCompose` in JavaScript, and `f` and `g` where unary while `h` binary, then `clojureCompose(f, g, h)(x, y)` would be equal to `f(g(h(x,y)))`.

Might be because I'm used to Haskell's automatically curryed functions, but I prefer Haskell's choice.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. One thing I didn't quite get is how "...restArgs expands to just 1 after the comma"? How the second value is being unpacked from an array?

Comment: I'm not expert, but the point is simply that if a function has a _parameter_ that is written as `...restArgs` then the corresponding _argument_ `restArgs` will be an array of all those args; when you write `...restArgs` in the body of the function, you expand that array to a comma separated thing. To see the difference, enter `((...x) => [...x, x])(1,2,3)` at the prompt and inspect the result.