# Eliminate consecutive duplicates from a string

Tags: haskell

I want to eliminate consecutive duplicates from a string like `f "aaabbbcccdeefgggg" = "abcdefg"`

This is my code

```
f :: String -> String
f "" = ""
f "_" = "_"
f (x : xs : xss)
    | x == xs   = f (xs : xss)
    | otherwise = x : f (xs : xss)
```

I got as error non-exhaustive patterns, I think it's from second line, the program doesn't know how to deal when it's only 1 char left. How should I fix it?

Comment: What is `f "_" = "_"` supposed to do?

Comment: when its only 1 char left in string, I think this is the problem

Comment: You only process one particula single-char string, there are more of them.

Comment: `"_"` matches the literal string `"_"`. I guess what you want is `[x]` to match a singleton list.

Comment: Then change it to `f [c] = [c]`

Comment: I believe the issue is best summarized as follows: the pattern `"a"` is a shorthand for the pattern `['a']` (or `'a':[]`) where `'a'` is a character literal -- this is not the same pattern as `[a]` (or `a:[]`) where `a` here is a variable name. In your case, you have the character literal `'_'` vs the wildcard pattern `_`, but the principle is the same -- these are distinct constructs.

Answer (score 23):

The `"_"` pattern does *not* match a string with any character, it matches the string that contains an underscore.

You can use `[_]` as pattern for the singleton string, so:

```
f :: String -> String
f "" = ""
f s@[_] = s
f (x : xs : xss)
    | x == xs   = f (xs : xss)
    | otherwise = x : f (xs : xss)
```

here we use `s@` to capture the string with one character as `s`.

or we can simplify this with:

```
f :: String -> String
f (x : xs : xss)
    | x == xs   = f (xs : xss)
    | otherwise = x : f (xs : xss)
f s = s
```

Answer (score 16):

> I want to eliminate consecutive duplicates from a string like `f "aaabbbcccdeefgggg" = "abcdefg"`

You can group the letters which are equal (via `Data.List.group`), and then take the first of each group (via `map head`, which applies `head` to each element of the list and gives you back the list of the results):

```hs
import Data.List (group) -- so we write group instead of Data.List.group
map head $ group "aaabbbcccdeefgggg"
```

This can be seen as the application of `map head` *after* the application of `group` to the input `String`.
Therefore, your `f` can be defined like the composition of those two functions:

```hs
f :: String -> String
f = map head . group
```

---

For completeness, as you seem to be new to Haskell, here are a few details:

- `Data.List.group "aaabbbcccdeefgggg"` returns `["aaa","bbb","ccc","d","ee","f","gggg"]`;
- `f $ a b c` is the same as `f (a b c)`;
- `.` is the composition operator, and it is such that `(f . g) x == f (g x)`.

  - Unrelated to this question, but important to bear in mind in general, `.` operates on unary functions, which means that if `g` takes more than one argument, the composition will pipe a partially applied `g` to `f` as soon as you give `f . g` one argument. In other words, if `g` is, say, binary, then `f (g x y)` is not equal to `(f . g) x y`, which will generally not even compile, but to `((f .) . g) x y`. Some more example about this, but in JavaScript, is in [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69298142/5825294), which should be fairly readable for a Haskell programmer.

Answer (score 7):

Or you can make it even simpler if you don't handle things that can be left unhandled:

```hs
f :: String -> String
f (x:y:xs) | x == y = f (y:xs)
f (x:xs) = x:f xs
f _ = ""
```

Answer (score 4):

To avoid looking ahead further than necessary, you shouldn't try to match on the first two elements. Instead, keep track of the *most recent* element.

```hs
f :: Eq a => [a] -> [a]
f = start
  where
    start [] = []
    start (x : xs) = x : go x xs

    go _old [] = []
    go old (x : xs)
      | x == old
      = go old xs
      | otherwise
      = x : go x xs
```

If you want, you can also write this as a *fold*, where you track whether you've seen an element yet using a `Maybe`:

```hs
f :: Eq a => [a] -> [a]
f xs = foldr go stop xs Nothing
  where
    stop _ = []
    go x r (Just old)
      | x == old = r (Just old)
    go x r _ = x : r (Just x)
```

Some may find the fold easier to read if it's rearranged a bit.

```
f :: Eq a => [a] -> [a]
f xs = (foldr go stop xs) Nothing
  where
    stop :: Maybe a -> [a]
    stop = \_ -> []

    go :: a -> (Maybe a -> [a]) -> (Maybe a -> [a])
    go x r = \acc -> case acc of
      Just old
        | x == old -> r (Just old)
      _ -> x : r (Just x)
```

Comment: at least indent your `= ...`s at least two more measly spaces than your `| ...`s. the guards and the RHSs are not the same thing. the cases should be clearly visually separated from one another.

Comment: @dfeuer Please explain your second solution. how foldr works on 4 argument in this example. I know we can use 4 argument on foldr but I can't get it in this example.

Comment: @WillNess, I like the equals signs to line up with the guard pipes. I guess I got used to that reading GHC code?

Comment: @s4seed3sm, I wrote a version that's rearranged a bit. Does that help? If not, can you explain what you find confusing? You should try to "translate" the fold version to the recursive function it represents.

Comment: with the explicit `f [] = []` we don't need the superfluous `Maybe` anymore and get to avoid the repeated construction/deconstruction of this data structure at each step. there is no real choice here -- we create it ourselves after all, in the fully not only predictable but known in advance pattern. more, we know we'll use the `Nothing` only once, at the very start. this needless creation of data to express known-in-advance control is fully an anti-pattern. (unconditional choice is no choice at all). it sometimes leads to a much shorter and cleaner code, and is near unavoidable; not here.

Comment: @WillNess, that's true from a clarity standpoint, but not from a list fusion standpoint. Guard it like that and you won't get fusion.

Comment: @dfeuer interesting, thanks. and your 2nd version, does it fuse? is `Just` de/constructed all the time or somehow is eliminated altogether?

Comment: if the problem is the two explicit clauses then they can be replaced by  [another `foldr` call](https://gist.github.com/treeowl/a864c00e3ba5b9662c200307413ac918#gistcomment-4035748). will _that_ get fused properly?

Comment: My code optimizes properly when marked `INLINABLE` and compiled with either `-O2` or `-O -fspec-constr`. See [this gist](https://gist.github.com/treeowl/dc4dbea63b6f5e887eed64f9a89b0e32). Fusing on the other side would require `build` and probably some `INLINE` fiddling.

Comment: @WillNess, your code will not fuse because `drop` doesn't work with list fusion at all.

Comment: does `tail` work? it is safe to call it there.

Comment: @WillNess, no, same thing. More fundamentally, though, you use `xs` *twice*, which is utterly incompatible with fusion.

Comment: dang. but if Maybes disappear, that's not needed after all. thanks for the clarifications.

Comment: @WillNess, yeah, if you look at the Core I pasted, you'll see it compiles to something that looks just like the two stage hand-written version. But as `potato` shows, it also fuses nicely.

Comment: [just one last thing](https://gist.github.com/treeowl/a864c00e3ba5b9662c200307413ac918#gistcomment-4035779) please. does it really not get fused just because of the two clauses, or I have misunderstood you?

Comment: In the first solution, is there some benefit to writing `f = start; start [] = ...` rather than `f [] = ...`? It seems like a pointless indirection to me.

Comment: @amalloy, it lets me avoid worrying about name shadowing warnings if I bind the same variable names in the patterns.

Answer (score 1):

You also could use `foldl`. the logic is: comparing the last element of accumulator with current element.

```haskell
f :: Eq a => [a] -> [a]
f xs = foldl (\x y -> if last x == y then x else x++[y] )  [head xs] xs
```

here we initiate our accumulator with `[head x]`.

Based on @dfeuer hint I change my solution:

```haskell
-- with foldl
f :: Eq a => [a] -> [a]
f xs = snd $ foldl  opr (Nothing, []) xs
  where
    opr (Just old, acc) n
      | old == n = (Just old, acc)
      | otherwise = (Just n, acc ++ [n])
    opr (Nothing, acc) n = (Just n, acc ++ [n])
```

```haskell
-- with foldr
f2 :: Eq a =>[a] -> [a]
f2 xs = snd $ foldr opr (Nothing, []) xs
  where
    opr n (Just old, acc)
      | old == n = (Just old, acc)
      | otherwise = (Just n, n:acc)
    opr n (Nothing, acc) = (Just n, n:acc)
```

Thanks to @dfeuer, I learned a lot of new things. This is the third version based on comments:

```haskell
-- with foldl
f :: Eq a => [a] -> [a]
f xs = snd $ foldl opr (Nothing, []) xs
  where
    opr (old, acc) n =
      ( Just n,
        case old of
          Just o
            | o == n -> acc
            | otherwise -> acc ++ [n]
          Nothing -> acc ++ [n]
      )
```

```haskell
-- with foldr
f :: Eq a => [a] -> [a]
f xs = snd $ foldr opr (Nothing, []) xs
  where
    opr n (old, acc) =
      ( Just n,
        case old of
          Just o
            | o == n -> acc
            | otherwise -> n : acc
          Nothing -> n : acc
      )
```

Comment: Can you see why that would be needlessly strict *and* hideously inefficient? Using partial functions like `head` and `last` when you don't need to is also frowned upon. An interesting challenge for you: write an *efficient*, *lazy* version using `foldr` instead of `foldl`. Hint: define appropriate `go` and `stop` to fill in the blanks in this definition: `f :: Eq a => [a] -> [a]; f xs = foldr _go _stop xs Nothing`. Yes, passing four arguments to `foldr` is *intentional*.

Comment: The second version is much less inefficient, and much cleaner. Nice work! It's still too strict, which will lead to garbage collection inefficiency for lists that aren't pretty short.

Comment: You can make your second version properly lazy using the fact that the result "shapes" are always the same, and the fact that in the first case `old = n`. Can you see how?

Comment: Try it first. Then check against this: https://gist.github.com/treeowl/a864c00e3ba5b9662c200307413ac918

Comment: Never mind, I don't think that modification is enough....